# Jetpack Compose not updating / recomposing Flow List Values from Room DB when DB Data is getting changed

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to show a List of Items in my  Android App. I'm using Jetpack Compose, Flows and RoomDB.

When **launching the Activity all Items are shown without any problems**, the **Flow get's items collected** and they are **displayed**.

But when I **change** some properties of the **Item in the Database**, the **changes are not displayed**. In my case I change the item to deleted, but it's still displayed as not deleted.

When I look at the **Database Inspector**, the **value is changed in the database** and set to deleted.
When I **log collecting the flow**, the **change is getting emitted** (It says the Item is set to deleted)
**But Jetpack Compose is not recomposing the change**.

If I **delete** an element from / **add** an element to the List (in the DB) the **UI gets updated and recomposed**.

So I can only assume that the problem must lie in the **recomposition** or handling of the flow.

Here my Code:

**My Activity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class StockTakingHistoryActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: StockTakingHistoryViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.stockList = ...

        setContent {
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        viewModel.getStockListItems(viewModel.stockList!!.uuid)
                    }

                    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                        Content(viewModel.stockListItems)
                    }

            }
        }
    }
...
    @Composable
    private fun Content(items: List<StockListItem>) {
            ...
                LazyColumn {
                    items(items) { item ->
                        HistoryItem(stockListItem = item)
                    }
                }
        }

    }
...
    @Composable
    private fun HistoryItem(stockListItem: StockListItem) {
        ...
        Text(text = stockListItem.deleted)
        ...
        Button(onClick = {
            viewModel.deleteItem(stockListItem)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Set to deleted!")
        }
                                    

    }
}
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
    var stockListItems by mutableStateOf(emptyList<StockListItem>())

    fun getStockListItems(uuid: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stockListItemRepository.findByUUID(uuid).collect { items ->
                Log.d("StockTakingHistoryViewModel", "items changed! ${items.map { it.deleted }}")
                stockListItems = items
            }
        }
    }
    fun deleteItem(stockListItem: StockListItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            stockListItemRepo.update(item.copy(deleted = true);
        }
    }
```

**The Repository:**

```
    fun findByUUID(uuid: String): Flow<List<StockListItem>> {
        return dao.findByUUID(uuid)
    }
```

The Dao behind the Repository Request:

```
    @Query("select * from StockListItem where stockListUUID = :uuid order by createdAt desc limit 30")
    fun findByUUID(uuid: String): Flow<List<StockListItem>>
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me! **Thank you!**

Comment: Do you see the line `... items changed! ...` in the logs when you add/delete an item?

Comment: Yes, i see the message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Problem: The `equals()` method of `StockListItem` only compared the primary key.

Comment: I also encounterd this problem, thanks for saving the day!!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can collect a flow as state (via `collectAsState`) I'd consider going that route for getting the list rather than calling `collect` in the viewModel and updating the `stockListItems` as there are fewer moving parts for things to go wrong.

For example something like the following:

```
setContent {

    val stockListItems = viewModel.getStockListItemsFlow(uuid).collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        Content(stockListItems)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the way I originally tried it. Unfortunately does not work!

Comment: Ah, it may be some thing with the LazyColumn then, but that seems odd to me because I thought without a provided ID the LazyColumn would simply replace them all with the new value. I'd throw a breakpoint on `HistoryItem(stockListItem = item)` and one on `LazyColumn {` as well. If the inner breakpoint isn't called but the outer one is, then it isn't properly detecting the differences. Is `StockListItem` a `data class` or does it implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods?

Comment: Found the Problem. The equals method only compared the primary keys

Comment: Yup, that would do it.